# What's the most efficient way of extracting information from huge files?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have to work with really big files (up to 1GB) and I need to extract some relevat information. Currently I parse the file line by line and extract only the information I need, but even so, it takes a lot of time.

I'm using electron because I need cross platform compatibility, what would be a good optimization?

My code looks something like this

```
const info = [];
readline.on("line", function(line) {
   if(condition(line)) {
      info.push(line);
   }
})
```

Comment: I don't know how fast `readline` is, but modules like [`binary-split`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binary-split) or [`line-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-stream) are pretty quick.